# AngularJS - function not working on ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function, controller

my scope function "login()" is not working when the user enter with the "ng-click" , why is not working? please help!

HTML

```
<a  id="login-button1" class="button button-assertive  button-block icon-right ion-log-in" ng-click="login()" >Entrar</a>
```

Funcion on controller

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', "Auth", '$state',
function ($scope, Auth, $stateParams) {

 $scope.login = function() {

    $signin_email = $scope.userloginForm.email.$modelValue;
    $signin_password = $scope.userloginForm.password.$modelValue;

     // sign in
      Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword($signin_email, $signin_password)
        .then(function(firebaseUser) {
          //$scope.message = "User created with uid: " + firebaseUser.uid;
          alert(firebaseUser.email + " logged in successfully!");
        }).catch(function(error) {

            alert(error.message);
          //$scope.error = error;
        });


    };



  }])
```

That is the form :

```
 <form id="login-form1" name="$parent.userloginForm" class="list" >
      <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
      <ion-list id="login-list1">
        <label class="item item-input" id="login-input1">
          <span class="input-label">Email :</span>
          <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="member.email" placeholder="">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input" id="login-input2">
          <span class="input-label">Senha :</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="member.password" placeholder="">
        </label>
      </ion-list>
      <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
      <a  id="login-button1" class="button button-assertive  button-block icon-right ion-log-in" ng-click="login()" >Entrar</a>
      <a href-inappbrowser="/signup" id="login-button2" class="button button-positive  button-block button-clear">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: provide more specific details ... "not working" tells us next to nothing of value. Take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: Try to update following in controller code.   
$signin_email = $scope.member.email;
$signin_password = $scope.member.password;

Comment: still dont working  @BanshiL.Dangi

Comment: @Mr.Malaka But do you have `$scope.member = {};` line, before `$scope.login...`? If you don't, try to add it.

Comment: @Mr.Malaka Rename form name to "userloginForm" and put $scope.member = {} just before the $scope.login method in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `$scope.member.email` instead of `$scope.userloginForm.email.$modelValue` and `$scope.member.password` instead of `$scope.userloginForm.password.$modelValue` inside `login` function, cause into this properties Angular writes from form's inputs. Of course, an the top of your controller, you should have `$scope.member = {}`. Also, I think your form's `name` should be `userloginForm`, not `$parent.userloginForm`. And one more thing - if you don't have to, you should not use `ng-click()` to submit form, you should `ng-submit="login"` on your form and `<button id="login-button1" class="button button-assertive  button-block icon-right ion-log-in type="submit">Entrar</button>`

Comment: where i have to put the scope.member = {}?

Comment: @Mr.Malaka just one line before `$scope.login...`.

Comment: like that: $scope.member{
    $scope.login = function() {
     
      ???

Comment: @Mr.Malaka Like that: `$scope.member = {}; $scope.login...`

Comment: dont work to me .. on console says that have an unexpected token in the line of scope.member{};

Comment: @Mr.Malaka Cause you forget `=`, it should be exactly like this: `$scope.member = {};`

Comment: nice ! i have forgot , but still in the same ... :/

Comment: @Mr.Malaka does console say something?

Comment: a lot of errors , like : Cannot read property '$modelValue' of undefined , Cannot set property 'email' of undefined

Comment: And do you use `$scope.member.email` instead of `$scope.userloginForm.email.$modelValue` and `$scope.member.password` instead of `$scope.userloginForm.password.$modelValue` inside `login` function? And do you change your form name to `userloginForm`?

Comment: @Mr.Malaka And when you got this errors? On simple page refresh, or on  login button click?

Comment: page refresh ... nothing happens when i click on the button (I put an alert to show me a message when it works , but nothing yet)

Comment: now , its clean ( that errors disapear!) but the function still dont working

Comment: @Mr.Malaka Ok, what is your `Entrar` button? `<a>` or `<button>`? Do you use `ng-click` on Entrar button or `ng-submit`?

Comment: i have tried both ... i put the ng-submit when you said , but now i put the ng-click back on <a> (i do not test the <button> yet) an error appears : Ignored call to 'alert()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.  is a good signal that the function was called!

Comment: @Mr.Malaka so your environment does not allow you to use alert, replace it with console.log and then function will be called. I encourage you to use button type submit and ng-submit on form, it's much more appropriate

Comment: Glad to help :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$scope.userloginForm.email.$modelValue` you can directly pass `ng-model` object as a parameter in the `login` function.

**In HTML :**

```
<a id="login-button1" class="button button-assertive  button-block icon-right ion-log-in" ng-click="login(member)" >Entrar</a>
```

**In controller :**

```
$scope.login = function(member) {
  var signin_email = member.email;
  var signin_password = member.password;
  console.log(signin_email);
  console.log(signin_password);
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.login = function(member) {
      var signin_email = member.email;
      var signin_password = member.password;
      console.log(signin_email);
      console.log(signin_password);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form id="login-form1" name="userloginForm" class="list" >
      <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
      <ion-list id="login-list1">
        <label class="item item-input" id="login-input1">
          <span class="input-label">Email :</span>
          <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="member.email" placeholder="">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input" id="login-input2">
          <span class="input-label">Senha :</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="member.password" placeholder="">
        </label>
      </ion-list>
      <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
      <a  id="login-button1" class="button button-assertive  button-block icon-right ion-log-in" ng-click="login(member)" >Entrar</a>
      <a href-inappbrowser="/signup" id="login-button2" class="button button-positive  button-block button-clear">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
    </form>
</div>
```